# How to find out what tries to load libmysqlclient_r.so library

Tags: c++, linux, gentoo, ldd

I am using clang-9 with mysql-connector-c++8.

After mysql-connector-c++ upgrade from 1.1.12 to 8.x and running function in my app: `get_driver_instance()` an exception is being thrown:

"Couldn't load library libmysqlclient_r.so: libmysqlclient_r.so: cannot open shared object file"

What I've tried so far:

- `ldd` on my newly compiled binary, but my newly compiled binary does not link against `libmysqlclient_r.so`.
- `strace -f` my binary, but no info about loading this library
- removed `/etc/ld.so.cache` and rebuilt it with `ldconfig`, than recompiled my software
- `updatedb && locate \*\.so | xargs ldd` and the same for `\*\.so\.\*`, but no file is showing it is linked with libmysqlclient_r.so

There are no errors during compilation. I've got out of ideas what might be wrong. What might I do to diagnose it further?

Comment: Does setting `LD_DEBUG=files` produce any clues? Also note that runtime `dlopen` calls will not produce anything in `ldd`.

Comment: @Botje: Yeah. Got: `      5538:     file=libmysqlclient_r.so [0];  dynamically loaded by /usr/lib64/libmysqlcppconn.so.7 [0]`. This .so.7 belongs to mysql-connector-c++ and it seems that this library is buggy. Tried to recompile it and my soft, but with no change.
Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime `dlopen` calls will not produce any output in `ldd`, but you can convince `ld.so` to print when a library is loaded by whom by setting the environment variable `LD_DEBUG=files`.